# Why aren't these divs displaying in the same line despite of "display:inline-block"?

Tags: html, css

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hryjLe13/)**

In the following SSCCE, I have applied `display:inline-block` to `div.content-text` and `div.content-image`. But still they are not displaying in the same line. Instead they are displaying like this:

[image]

**I want them to display in the same line, in the blue box. Why aren't they, despite the `display:inline-block;`? How should I get this to work?**

```css
.content-box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 350px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 5px solid blue;
}
.content-box .content-image {
  width: 35%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  /*border: 5px solid orange;*/
}
.content-box .content-text {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  color: #1c1a1a;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 100;
  overflow-y: auto;
  /*border: 5px solid #52e007;*/
  height: 100%;
  width: 65%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>

<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
</head>

<body>

  <div class="content-box">


    <div class="content-text">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>


    <div class="content-image" style="background-image:url(http://www.penttila-gardens.com/activities/walking/countryside/images/02-harvest.jpg)"></div>


  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have applied this `inline-block` layout to inner elements `.content-box .content-image` and `.content-box .content-text`, not container `.content-box`. After that, you should remove white spaces between elements (they are appearing due to inline layout), for example, by applying`font-size: 0` (or [`word-spacing: -100%`](http://jsfiddle.net/hryjLe13/1/)) to the `.content-box`.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hryjLe13/2/)

Comment: Hi, I used `display:inline-block` on the `.content-box` because initially it was a part of a bigger markup, in which I wanted to have a couple other elements next to `.content-box`. I could not get that to work so I wrote this SSCCE to understand this. I forgot to remove those styles here.

Comment: Actually Yes, But by adding `display:inline` again to the `.content-box` and then also to the next inline element I just added. [JSFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/hryjLe13/7/) Thank you so very much. Here I set `font-size:0` on `.parent` to remove the white space between inline elements, but there is still tiny 1px looking space between `.content-box` and `.notch`. But I can use negative margin to solve that.

Comment: Now I am confused on which answer to accept. I am thankful for both the answers, but I am especially thankful to you for answering the follow-up; and I am especially thankful to the other answerer because they also added a link to a short article which explains the thing to me. :s

Comment: @Solace: Well, you can choose whatever answer you like, just don't forget about it.

Comment: Normally I would try that the person with lesser votes gets upvotes (when there is a tie between answers), but I am going to choose this one because you asked. Thanks again. I request you to upvote the other answer, so that they also get upvotes that way. Sorry if this sounds to be lacking much sense.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should use the display property in the chuilds, not in the parent. Second, there's a problem with a space between display-inline elements (https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/). I used the negative amrgin solution, but there's others in the link.

Right now I cannt testet in other browsers (only chrome and IE 8 to 10). But you have to think in what do you need and the browser support. Maybe use float or flexbox instead could be better depending on your needs.

```css
.content-box {
  width: 350px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 5px solid blue;
}
.content-box > div {
  display: inline-block;
}
.content-box .content-image {
  width: 35%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  /*border: 5px solid orange;*/
}
.content-box .content-text {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  color: #1c1a1a;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 100;
  overflow-y: auto;
  /*border: 5px solid #52e007;*/
  height: 100%;
  width: 65%;
margin-right: -4px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>

<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
</head>

<body>

  <div class="content-box">


    <div class="content-text">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>


    <div class="content-image" style="background-image:url(http://www.penttila-gardens.com/activities/walking/countryside/images/02-harvest.jpg)"></div>


  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Here’s an article you should read, to understand the basic issue with inline-block elements and whitespace between the element tags: https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: Thank you so very much for your answer, more so for linking to the article because now I understand what was happening. The other answer appeared above yours, so I followed up with that answer, and the answerer answered to my follow-up, so I am particularly thankful to them as well. Otherwise I would mark your answer as accepted. So it's a very good answer, because you linked to the article where the questioner can learn rather than just get the code running. So thank you.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you very much. I have read the article, and it is very useful.